# Build Gradle error while jdk install?

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Android studio give me error every time bellow see screen shot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6gvi.png)

I have latest android studio installed in MAC OSX, and latest JDK 8.0 installed on system both it still gives me this error can anyone help to solve this error. 
And i have downloaded all the API from 15 to 23 with their documents and other parts including extras as well as(Using SDK manager).

Comment: show me your jdk location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the directory to: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home` in JDK settings solved my issue. I had the same problem getting started up. Hope this helps!